# Variable z-index parent and order childs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, I have an parent element with some childs. Let's say the parent has an *X* `z-index`. I want the first child `z-index` to be parent `z-index` minus 1. The next child parent minus 2, third minus 3 and so on. This all has to be variable, so **no** hardcoding! And yes, I can change the order of the HTML elements in this example, but I receive this elements via an external service so thats impossible.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent"> Z-index = X
  <div class="child" id="child_1">Z-index = X - 1</div>
  <div class="child" id="child_2">Z-index = X - 2</div>
  <div class="child" id="child_3">Z-index = X - 3</div>
</div>
```

In this example, I want my parent on top of the childs and then `#child_1` on top of `#child_2` and `#child_3` at the bottom.

This is possible with JS but I rather use CSS, can I change this with CSS only?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/snb71q43/5/)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, its little bit unclear to me.

Comment: it's not possible without JS. because css have not any viability of loops but you do with SASS & LESS

Comment: Someone will correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's not possible for a _child element_ to have a lower `z-index` than its _parent container_.

Comment: if parent z-index fixed then we can achieve this

Comment: All right @VijayArun if parent z-index is 100, can you create an answer for me? thanks:)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Can you please take a look at the fiddle? The elements are now from top-bottom 3-2-1 and i want 1-2-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution in CSS...

I've done it with JQuery and it works:

```
$(".child").each(function(index){  
    $(this).css("z-index", "-" + index);
});
```